# Does a recursive Ant task exist to recover properties from external file?

Tags: java, svn, ant

I ve got a problem in getting properties with ant from a properties file. With a simple target like this in my build.xml, i'd like to get at least two properties path1 and path2.   I'd like to have a generic target to get this two properties....   in order to avoid modifying the build.xml (just adding a new prop)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance !

**build.xml :**

```
<target name="TEST" description="test ant">
    <property file="dependencies.properties"/>  
    <svn>  
        <export srcUrl="${path.prop}" destPath="${workspace}/rep/" />  
    </svn>  
</target>
```

**dependencies.properties :**

```
path1.prop = /path/to/src1
path2.prop = /path/to/src2
```

Comment: do you want to iterate over path[i].prop where i is in [1..n]?

Comment: Yes that's it. I'm looking for a simple issue. 
i thought about using javascript but as i am not an ant master user,
i think there is a easy way to do that with ant.
thanks

Comment: If it works you should accept the answer or at least give an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it works.
in addition you can use the propertycopy from ant-contrib to get other properties from the file.

```
dependencies.list=path1,path2
path1.prop1=val1
path1.prop2=val2
path2.prop1=val3
path2.prop2=val4
```

like this :

```
<target name="main">
    <property file="dependencies.properties"/>
    <foreach list="${dependencies.list}" delimiter="," param="name" target="doExtract" inheritall="true"/>
</target>

<target name="doExtract">
    <propertycopy name="prop1" from="${name}.prop1" silent="true"/>
    <propertycopy name="prop2" from="${name}.prop2" silent="true"/>
    <svn>
        <export srcUrl="${prop1}" destPath="${workspace}/rep/"" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your path settings to a comma separated list in a single property and use a [foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608935/ant-foreach-loop)