# how to do for loop based on a limit in Ant

Tags: ant-contrib

In Ant-contrib, we can do something like:

```
<for list="a,b,c,d" param="instence">
```

But if I don't have a list, I only have a limit, e.g. limit=4.

Is there a way to do for loop based on limit, like:

```
<for limit="4" param="index">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Ant addon **[Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)** provides some solutions for your problem.

1) Use a while loop

the test attribute evaluates some EL expression,
 which maybe a simple counter, f.e.

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

 <!-- some counter -->
 <fl:let>
  countdown = 3
 </fl:let>

 <fl:while test=" countdown >= 0 ">
  <fl:echo>
   #{countdown > 0 ? countdown : 'bang!' }..
  </fl:echo>
  <fl:let>
   countdown = countdown - 1
  </fl:let>
 </fl:while>

</project>
```

output:

```
  [fl:echo] 3..
  [fl:echo] 2..
  [fl:echo] 1..
  [fl:echo] bang!..
```

or some other expression, f.e. checking for existence of a file, means looping until some file exists :

```
 <fl:while test=" !'/home/rosebud/stop'.tofile.isfile ">
  <fl:echo>
   still working..
  </fl:echo>
 </fl:while>
```

2) Use a for loop with break or continue :

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

 <fl:for var="i" in=" list(1,2,3,4,5,6) ">
    <fl:echo>i = #{i}</fl:echo>
    <fl:break test=" i == 3 " />
 </fl:for>

  <fl:for var="i" in=" list(1,2,3,4,5,6) ">
    <fl:continue test=" i > 3 " />
    <fl:echo>i = #{i}</fl:echo>
 </fl:for>

</project>
```

which gives the same result :

```
  [fl:echo] i = 1
  [fl:echo] i = 2
  [fl:echo] i = 3
```

See more details in the **[Flaka manual](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual)**

Comment: Thanks. I am using Flaka. Can you take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679224/how-to-include-ant-flaka-jar

Comment: Currently writing an answer to that question.Please keep patient for some mins :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
<project name="Attachments" default="print">
    <property name="numAttachments" value="20" />
    <target name="generate">
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            var list = '1';
            var limit = project.getProperty( "numAttachments" );
            for (var i=2;i<limit;i++)
            { 
                list = list + ',' + i;
            }
            project.setNewProperty("list", list);            
        ]]>
        </script>    
    </target>
    <target name="print" depends="generate">
        <for list="${list}" param="letter">
            <sequential>
                <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not exactly what you want, but [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/109215/tools/Creating-loops-ANT) has an example.  Essentially, you pass in the limit as a list of numbers.  Its not elegant, but it works.

[Here's another idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608935/ant-foreach-loop) - see the answer by user "cn1h".  Its a cool way to get around limitations in ANT - embed a script from another language which can do what you want.  Nice!

Comment: +1 No standard way to do what the OP is asking for. I can't think of any different solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In antcontrib you can also do:

```
<for param="index" end="@{numberOfIterations}" start="1">
```

But be aware of a [bug](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/Looping-number-of-times-tp1356385p1356394.html#a1356394): It is unable to handle 
begin and end being the same. So when "numberOfIterations" equals 1 you get an error.

We got a workaround for this, checking the value of numberOfIterations first and only when its not 1 doing the for-statement.

```
<if><equals  arg1="1" arg2="@{numberOfIterations}"/>
<then>
   ....
</then>
<else>
   <for param="index" end="@{numberOfIterations}" start="1">
   ....
</else>
</if>
```