# How to include Ant flaka jar?

Tags: ant, flaka

I am writing ant scripts and using Ant flaka jar to do some work.

But flaka doesn't work as other external Ant lib.

For example, if I need to include ant-contrib:

```
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
  <classpath>
        <pathelement location="../../lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
  </classpath>
  </taskdef>
```

Most importantly, I can specify where the jar is located.

But for flaka, I don't see such thing. In the official website, they just tell user to download flaka jar to Ant installation folder.

How can I specify where is the flaka jar when I want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all some general recommendation. Any external lib has to be in sight for ant, means on path.
The most primitive approach is to put your ant addons in $ANT_HOME/lib, but that 'pollutes' your ant installation.
Put your external libs in it's own location, f.e. /ant_xtralibs and use the -lib parameter via Ant_ARGS.
The [Flaka manual](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual) section 2 has some notes about that, more details in the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline).

Your example dealing with antcontrib uses the traditional approach via taskdef resource..
The modern - recommended - way is to use a XML namespace declaration, as the Flaka Manual mentions
 right before section 2 :
"Thus all build file snippets shown assume that the build file contains the following XML namespace declaration"

It's also possible to use Flaka via taskdef the traditional way:

```
<project>
  <taskdef resource="it/haefelinger/flaka/antlib.xml">
   <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/home/rosebud/flaka/ant-flaka-1.02.02.jar"/>
   </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <!-- when on path via -lib or ANT_ARGS it's enough to use : -->
  <taskdef resource="it/haefelinger/flaka/antlib.xml"/>

  <logo>
   Hello, #{property['ant.file'].tofile.name}
  </logo>

</project>
```

output

```
Trying to override old definition of datatype filterset
Trying to override old definition of task fail
Trying to override old definition of task echo
[logo] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[logo] :                               Hello, demo.xml                                :
[logo] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

note the lines starting with "Trying to override.."
That's because of Flaka extends some ant tasks

but if you put Flaka in it's own namespace :

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <fl:logo>
  Hello, #{property['ant.file'].tofile.name}
 </fl:logo>
</project>
```

output

```
[fl:logo] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[fl:logo] :                               Hello, demo.xml                                :
[fl:logo] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

no more "Trying to override..." means no more collision with ant's own tasks, as Flaka resides in it's own namespace

So to make it short : 
1) use ANT_ARGS to bring your extralibs (Flaka .. etc.) in the game
2) use the modern way of Namespace declaration

**EDIT** after comment asking for namespace combined with classpath **EDIT**

yes that works, see [Ant manual for details about antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html), especially the section 
"Load antlib from inside of the buildfile", for Flaka you would use something like :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <taskdef uri="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka"
  resource="it/haefelinger/flaka/antlib.xml"
  classpath="path/to/flaka.jar"/>
```

but i believe you still didn't get the advantages of using $ANT_ARGS
simply use some script to start your ant scripts, f.e. :

for Windows
set JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk\1.6.0_26
set ANT_HOME=C:\ant
set ANT_ARGS=-lib C:\ant_xtralibs;C:\ant_testlibs
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\cvsnt

:: default
call ant -f %1

:: debug
::call ant -debug -f %1
... etc.

for Linux/Unix - don't forget the quotationmarks on the ANT_ARGS line !
...
ANT_ARGS="-lib /usr/local/ant_xtralibs:/usr/local/ant_testlibs"
export ANT_ARGS
...

You don't need to use taskdef with classpath anymore !!
Using the -lib option to load additional libraries has another benefit.
There are some libs which must be loaded before Ant (f.e. BSF, js, xml)
starts parsing the buildfile.

ANT_ARGS is a special environment variable. Its content is automatically
added to the invocation of Ant.

-- Other possibilities --

1)
put those 'set ANT_ARGS ...' stuff into =

Linux/Unix
$ANT_HOME/bin/ant

Windows
%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat

disadvantage = changes the ant core installation, remember
your changes before you copy your ant installation to
another machine and strange things happen !

2)
put your extralibs in ${user.home}/.ant/lib
advantage = every user may use his own set of libraries

consult the Ant manual for details :
http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline
http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#libs

Comment: But is it possible to define the namespace and use spcific classpath at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed flaka in under 1 minute. Simply put the .jar into your ..ant/lib dir as they indicate in the installation instructions.

Run this :

```
<project xmlns:c="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <c:logo>
  Hello, #{property['ant.file'].tofile.name}
 </c:logo>
</project>
```

As they also say in the site. If the output is different than this :

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Stefanos\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\stackOverflow\stackOverflow\build.xml
[c:logo] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[c:logo] :                               Hello, build.xml                               :
[c:logo] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Check your java version. It must be >= 1.5. Your ant should be >= 1.7 and last but not least check your permissions.

Comment: yep, it works, but see Flaka Manual section 2.2 : "The most primitive technique is to save ant-flaka-x.y.z.jar into Ant's library folder lib." Better to keep your ant core installation clean and use ANT_ARGS for all external libs ! Also sometimes you have no permissions to put new stuff in $ANT_HOME/lib - for good reasons ;-)

Comment: Well in any case when one follows the installation page it should not be a problem. I personally have 0 experience with flaka but I managed to run it very easily by simply following the steps there. I am sure there are better - cleaner ways to use it of course.

Comment: my recommendation - as also stated in the Flaka manual - is not specific to Flaka but applys for any external lib; keeping the ant core installation clean is best practice